# Fonts Menu PyQt5 Text Editor

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qfont

**The Problem:**

I am trying to find a way of adding a font style to text that as written by the user of my PyQt5 text editor program. I don't want to code each font into some kind of menu manually and I am wondering if there is a built-in way for the user to select their font style for their text like this (Notepad font picker):

[image: Notepad fonts]

My code currently looks like this:

```
class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'Text Editor'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 1080
        self.height = 920

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.lbl    = QLabel(self)

        self.text = QTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.widget.layout().addWidget(self.text)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.initUI()



   def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        toolBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = toolBar.addMenu('File')
        editMenu = toolBar.addMenu('Edit')
        toolsMenu = toolBar.addMenu('Tools')
        helpMenu = toolBar.addMenu('Help')

        fontButton = QAction('Configure Editor', self)
        fontButton.setShortcut('Ctrl+E')
        fontButton.triggered.connect(lambda: self.font_set)
        toolsMenu.addAction(fontButton)

        self.show()

   def font_set(self):
        print("Display Fonts")


if __name__ == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = App()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt has a widget called `QFontDialog`, and that is perfect for this case, in the following part I show an example of its use:

```
def font_set(self):
    font, ok = QFontDialog.getFont(self.text.font(), self)
    if ok:
        #QApplication.setFont(font)
        self.text.setFont(font)
        print("Display Fonts", font)
```

*Note:* You must change the following statement:

```
fontButton.triggered.connect(lambda: self.font_set)
```

to:

```
fontButton.triggered.connect(self.font_set)
```

Screenshot:

[image]